# How to Change position of cursor or position of scrollbar using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have used Android phonegap application for creating dynamic list with label and corresponding values for that label one by one (e.g. label: 'A', values: Arun, Amala, Aruna up to 'Z') and there are alphabets in side of the page.

Now I want that when I am clicking alphabet ('A') the list automatically show the label ('A') with values, if it is 'B' show that label ('B') with values without modifying the list.

While I am clicking 'A', how to get current position of label ('A') and move the cursor to that postion show the label ('A') with values?

My code: I have retrive value from local database,below code is for dynamic list Script:

```
function querySuccess(tx,results)
{


 $('.sidemenu').append("<label style='background-color:#C1CDD9'   align='left'>"+results.rows.item(i).alphabet + "</label>"+"<br/>");
for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) 
                {

 $(".sidemenu").append("<li  id='list' >"+"<a id='link'  href='#'>" +results.rows.item(i).name +  "</a>"+ "<br/>"+ "</li>");
 }
```

html

```
<ul class="sidemenu" ></ul>
```

My dynamiclist like:

```
label-A
```

Arun
Aruna
Amala
label-B
Bala
bhuvana

Comment: You cannot change the position of the mouse, ever.

Comment: ok Thank you  .i have list in a div and i set scroll bar for that div.How to change the position of the scroll bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you need to use the [scrollTop Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop)

First, we declare a variable for the container of the items we need to scroll through.

```
var container = $('.sidemenu'); // this is our div
```

Then our click function

```
$("#A").click(function(){
  scrollTo = $(this); // wherever our element with an Id of "A" is;

  //the magic
  container.scrollTop( scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop() );
});
```

This should scroll directly to the item within your .sidemenu list.

Comment: i got error like this scrollTo.offset() is null,not an object

Comment: what is scrollTo = $(this);?what value for this?i got the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the position of the mouse, but you can change the scroll position through javascript.

```
$(window).scrollTop(400); // height in px
```

or to do it smoothly animated:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop : 400}, "fast");
```

[scrollTop jQuery page](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Comment: Its working well when srollbar is on top otherwise it moves to wrong position and also its working in brower not in emulator.Its not working well.when i click the button  "a" ,the  scroll bar move to label "a" in the dynamic list.when i click the button  "s" ,the  scroll bar move to label "s" in the dynamic list.